# JAX Mac M1 CPU [Import Issue]

Tags: python, jax

Hi I'm currently using Mac M1 and followed these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/saqibameen/e33612ca731407639dd31776d2f532ab#)
to install Jax/Jaxlib.

The pip installs worked fine, but when I attempt to run the file, I get this error: RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.

I'm confused because according to the Jax [documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#pip-installation-cpu), it seems like that they have support for Mac M1 CPU.